# Android, XMLParser - Reading XML

Tags: android, xml

im currently trying to read and XML from a web server in my Android App, but im not sure how to search for the TAGS, and all the examples i see are not unlike mine:

```
<document>    
<producer/>
<metadata></metadata>

<recorddata count="111">
<row>
<field name="numint" value="MTAwMQ=="/>
<field name="Grupo" value="NQ=="/>
<field name="Link" value="Q29ycmllbnRlcw=="/>
<field name="Nombre" value="Q29ycmllbnRlcw=="/>
<field name="Valor" value="MzQwMC4wMA=="/>
</row>
</recorddata>
</document>
```

I need to read the ROWS inside RECORDATA, but im not sure how to address this problem, this is my code:

```
private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Record> Records = null;
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        Record currentRecord = null;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = null;
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    Records = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name == "row"){
                        currentRecord = new Record();
                    } else if (currentRecord != null){
                        if (name == "numint"){
                            currentRecord.numint = parser.getText();
                        } else if (name == "Grupo"){
                            currentRecord.group = parser.getText();
                        } else if (name == "Link"){
                            currentRecord.link= parser.getText();
                        }else if (name == "Nombre") {
                            currentRecord.name= parser.getText();
                        }else if (name == "Valor") {
                            currentRecord.value= parser.getText();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("row") && currentRecord != null){
                        Records.add(currentRecord);
                    }
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
        printProducts(Records);
    }
```

BUT, the Records List IS EMPTY at the end of the process, and i can tell is doing something, because there are a lot of records and it takes like 2 minutes till the process is over.

Im not sure if im using the getName() correctly, should i be checking for field??? and if so, how do i know in which field im on. Should i be using nextToken() instead???

Comment: I realize now that the getText() is not getting anything, because there is no text :p i'll try to make some modifications

Comment: hmm i dont know how to get the Attribute Value of 'Value' :p

Comment: Have you ever tried to use SAX Parser?

Answer (score 1):

I Solved the problem by rewriting my code as follows:

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("row")){
                        currentRecord = new Record();
                    } else if (currentRecord != null) {
                        if(parser.getName().equals("field")) {
                            if(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("numint")) {
                                currentRecord.numint = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                            }else if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("Grupo")) {
                                currentRecord.group = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                            }else if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("Link")) {
                                currentRecord.link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                            }else if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("Nombre")) {
                                currentRecord.name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                            }else if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name").equalsIgnoreCase("Valor")) {
                                currentRecord.value = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
```

Taking something the answer by Andreaoid, and a little tweaking, i could the read de xml file without issue

Answer (score 0):

To get an attribute you can use the method:

```
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
```

Definition:

```
public abstract String getAttributeValue (String namespace, String name)
```

Taken from help:

*Added in API level 1. Returns the attributes value identified by namespace URI and namespace localName. If namespaces are disabled namespace must be null. If current event type is not START_TAG then IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown.*

Pay attention: *Replace all the String comparisons*!

```
name == "row"
```

With:

```
name.equals("row")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That actually did help a little, the List is not empty anymore, But now Im getting all Null Values, Every Element inside the list is populated with Records with null values

Comment: For eg,
Row 1:
numint: Null
Group: Null
Link: Null
Name: Null
Value: Null

Comment: im getting this XML from a webserver, the php process the Data inside an SQL database and sends it as an XML Document

Comment: Another Question: the getName() is retrieven the Attribute Name??? or the name of the Tag: "field", is the name of the Tag right???

Comment: getName() retrieves the current tag name.
Can you post the Xml URL?